# Magento guest checkout accordion related problems

Tags: magento, checkout

Within the Magento guest checkout mechanism checkout/onepage, the following 2 accordion related problems are experienced:

Problem 1:
When Billing Information (2/6) is completed with the [same shipping address] option selected, the Continue button click makes the next Shipping Information (3/6) accordion green but does not open that accordion.

Problem 2:
When that green Shipping Information (3/6) accordion is then clicked on, and the Continue button clicked for the Shipping Method (4/6) accordion to be opened next, the page jumps some down and does not stay in the correct position for the latest accordion selected, so that the guest then has to scroll some up.

Have you experienced the same, or do you know what can be the reason?

Comment: Do you have a link to your website? Most probably you have some error in the response of the ajax calls or there is a js issue.

Comment: I see that you are missing the region field. For some countries this field must be a dropdown, for others a text field. Put it back and see if it works.

Comment: When the region field is now reintroduced, it all works. Thanks for the hint! Is there no possibilities for this region field to be removed?

Comment: Unfortunately I never tried it before. For sure there is a way, but I don't know how.  I suggest you write as an answer to this question what you found and mark it as accepted. Then ask an other question about removing the region. You can ask it here: http://magento.stackexchange.com. you may have a better chance.

Answer (score 0):

When the region field is now reintroduced, it all works. Thanks Marius for the hint!